# Struct and array to populate sections of Tableview in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, struct, sections

I have  a struct (getItems) that defines a post
when I read my posts, I store them in an array like so :

```
var posts = [getItems]()
```

problem is :
I ve decided to create sections in my tableview
How can I create an array of posts ?
I ve tried to declare `var items = [posts]()` but this doesn t work

I also have a item counter that counts how many items should be in each section, but I can't figure out how to split my array of getItems into something like :

[index1 : [getItems1, getItems2 ...], index2:[getItems1, getItems2 ...]...]

this so I could call sections and row in my TableView

Sincerely
PS : I didn't post any code since it's a lot of data here ...

Comment: Your question is too vague. Do you just want to split the `posts` to several subarrays according to a counter?

Comment: yes Exactly, i need to segregate them in sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is want you want. Let's say if you have a `counter` function that will take an section index as parameter and return how many posts should be in this particular section.

```
func counter(index: Int) -> Int {
    return index
}
```

Then calculate your subarrays like this:

```
var currentIndex = 0
var totalCount = 0
var sections: [Int: [getitems]] = [:]
while totalCount < posts.count {
    let currentCounter = counter(currentIndex)
    sections[currentIndex] = posts.suffixFrom(totalCount).prefix(currentCounter).flatMap { $0 }
    currentIndex++
    totalCount += currentCounter
}
```

And then in your `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return sections[section].count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for wastin your time, was simple, I was mistaken in the way I was trying to declare an array of array

just had to do

```
data = [[getitems]]()
```

Comment: oh god, this was handy, I made the same mistake.